# Is the given function injective?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Let me say it with words: For some $\alpha$, if I choose $(x,y)$, then there is a quadruple $(a,b,c,d)$ which satisfies the mapping:

$$x=\left(\frac{((1-\alpha)a+c)d}{c((1-\alpha)(b-1)+d)}\right)^\frac{1}{\alpha-1}, \quad y={\left(\frac{((1-\alpha)(a-1)+c)d}{c((1-\alpha)b+d)}\right)^\frac{1}{\alpha-1}}$$
Then would it be possible to pick some $\alpha$ such that for every $(x,y)$ there is only one corresponding $(a,b,c,d)$ but not more?

Here $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ are variables and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0,1\}$ is a parameter that can be chosen.

Have any ideas?

Comment: Seyhmus Your comment on my "answer" below is correct. I deleted it. But the last bit about a continuous bijection still says there should be no such $\alpha.$ I'll try again for a concrete example...

Comment: Sheymus-- Please read my adjusted answer below. It gives an infinite collection of a,b,c,d points all mapping to the specific point $(x,y)=(1,1).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k=1-\alpha$ and note the restriction $\alpha \neq 0,1$ then becomes $k \neq 0,1.$ Then the transform is, after taking the $-k$th powers of the sides,
$$x^{-k}=\frac{(ka+c)d}{c(k(b-1)+d)}, \\ y^{-k}=\frac{(k(a-1)+c)d}{c(kb+d)}. \tag{1}$$
We claim this map cannot be one-to one. Specifically we can produce an infinite set of inputs using $a,b,c,d$ all of which map to the same point $(1,1).$
Note that if we take $a=0,b=1$ then $x^{-k}=1$ from (1) no matter what $c,d$ are (as long as neither is $0$). Now for any $m$ other than $1$ if we put $c=-k(m-1)$ and $d=k/(m-1),$ then, keeping in mind we have already chosen $a=0,b=1,$ we find from (1) that $y^{-k}=1.$
Thus we have infinitely many points $(a,b,c,d)=(0,1,-k/(m-1),k/(m-1))$ all of which map by the transform (1) to the point $(x,y)=(1,1).$ Note our requirement mentioned above that neither of $c,d$ be zero is met here since $k \neq 0$ by assumption. [I noticed later we also need $m \neq 0$ in the above.]

Comment: I didnt understand well. For example, If $k=2$ and $a$ and $c$ are some values such that $(3)$ holds, then this $(a,a,c,c)$ will results in some $(x,y)$ for which $x=y$. But if we choose another $a$ and $c$ such that $(3)$ holds then, this time we will get another $(x,y)$ such that $x=y$. Although both will give $x=y$ this value will be different in two difference cases. Am I missing something? What are the concere $(a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2)$ such that for both cases I get $(x_1,y_1)$ s.t. $x_1=y_1$?

Comment: that sounds good. thx.

Comment: Btw, I was wondering whether the other way around is injective. I mean from $\mathbbb{R^2\to \mathbbb{R^4}$. Do you have any idea? I am also thinking about a new question.

Comment: I'm curious as to what motivates your mapping-- where does it "come from". Including that in a future question might improve it. I'll think about R2 to R4 injectivity when I get a chance.

Comment: it is about a design of hypothesis testing in a robust way. To do this one needs to solve 4 non-linear equations in 4 parameters. There is a straightforward (but quite non-trivial) way to reduce these 4 equations to 2. The solution in 4 parameters i unique, if one can find it. But the problem is that now we are dealing with reduced equations.. and the concern is whether the solution in 2 equations with 2 parameters is also unique or not...

Comment: @SeyhmusGungoren From $R^2$ to $R^4$ to not be injective means we need two points $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ to map to the same point $(a,b,c,d)$ in $R^4.$ But then the map itself already determines $x,y$ uniquely. So I can't figure what it means for the question of injective from $R^2$ to $R^4.$ Also I don't see a map from $R^2$ to $R^4$ in the first place. Could you spell out what you mean by injective/noninjective in your recent comment?

Comment: First, thanks for the comment. Yes, the question is whether there exists two pairs $(x,y)$ and $(x^{'},y^{'})$ which map to the same point $(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}$. The claim is there there exist no such two pairs. For ever $(x,y)$, there are possible uncountably many $(a,b,c,d)$. The corresponding $(a,b,c,d)$ can be found via solving the two equations. The questions is wheter those solutions will coinside for  $(x,y)$ and $(x^{'},y^{'})$.